# How to configure hibernate properties without persistence xml

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a Spring MVC web setup with a Spring ORM/Hibernate persistence layer. I have configured my `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` to auto-scan for persistence entities on a package so I don't need persistence xml configuration.

How can I set up my beans configuration so it shows the generated queries and refreshes the database with model changes on startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` extends `AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean`, which contains `setJpaProperties(Properties)` method. You can pass custom properties to this bean using this method.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(properties);
```

Or if you want to do it on the Spring config files:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    ...
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    ...
</bean>
```

[JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#setJpaProperties-java.util.Properties-)